# Is it ok to user multiple submit buttons is asp.net web pages

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
@{

    var db = Database.Open("DataExample");
    var sql = "Select * from FenixProducts";

    if(IsPost){
        if(Request["button"].Equals("Filter1")){
            sql = "Select * from FenixProducts where TorchLumens > 1200";
        }
        if(Request["button"].Equals("Filter2")){
            sql = "Select * from FenixProducts where TorchLumens < 200";
        }
    }
    var productResult = db.Query(sql);
}

@foreach(var x in productResult){
    @ProductHelpers.fenixTorchGenerateProcuct(x.TorchName, x.TorchLumens, x.TorchRange, x.TorchPrice)
}

<form action="" method="post" style=" clear: left;">
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="Filter1">Filter1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="Filter2">Filter2</button>
</form>
```

Is it a good practise? I plan to use multiple buttons in the same form and filter products based on the button clicked.

Comment: Don't see why it's a problem. I do it all the time.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in the value you're looking for as a parameter and use one button with a selector (dropdownlist, textbox, etc.)?

Comment: GSerg: I am working on asp.net webpages in webmatrix ".cshtml" files. It's a small project with max 5 pages. I guess your comment applies if I am working on MVC, let me know if I am correct.

Comment: Thanks Tim... seems like a neat solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bad practice to use multiple buttons. There is no point to restrict that, however, you should separate your backend code from your view and you should make sure your pages are easy to use.

In your case two buttons could resolve your problem, but if you need to enable many possible customizing scenarios, then a search could be customized by `select` and `input` tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

it is ok for a demo page, or you do it for fun.

but it's not a good idea to do that in a real project. that will become a nightmare for you to maintain that project.

1. you are mixing busniess logic, database access in the view.
2. what if you want a third filter in future? add one more button?

you can use a radio button or dropdownlist as the input of that form and post that input back to your handler, handle the logic base on the value of the input.
then move your handler into another file, post the form to that file, to seprate the responsibility.

if you are working on a webform project, write the logic in your .cs file and if you are working on a mvc project, write the logic in your controller

Comment: Sean, I am neither on mvc nor webforms.. .. I am working on webpages in webmatrix. Is there any security issue with what I have done?

Comment: ok, I see. The code in the @{} will be compiled to binary file on the server, so the code in `@{}` is not visible from client, and sql statement is hardcoded, there is no chance for sql injection, you are safe in this case.

please consider my suggestion to seprate the server side code and client code into different file, at least you can post your form to another page to handle to server side logic, by default it will post to the current page if you leave action the empty. trust me, that will save you lots of time in the future